# correspondence between meromorphic functions on complex torus vs. $\mathbb{C}$ itself

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I have an integration to do along the path which is the border of a parallelogram, 
namely, I need to show using integration the sum of the orders on the complex torus is $0$.

I reparameterized it correctly, and solved the problem, by showing that $\gamma_1,\gamma_3$ cancel and so do the other two when orientation is chosen correctly. Letting $\omega_1,\omega_2$ be my linearly independent elements of $\mathbb{C}$, I need to show that I can shift my problem over to $\mathbb{C}$ as we have not learned integration on Riemann Surfaces yet, then bring it back to the torus. In doing so I concluded that there's a 1-1 correspondence between meromorphic functions defined on the complex torus and meromorphic defined on $\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Let

$f: \mathbb{C} / L \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

be meromorphic, this corresponds to

$F: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

which is meromorphic and doubly periodic, that is $F(\omega_i+z)=F(\omega)$ for $i=1,2$

and is defined via $F(z)=f(z)$ for when $z \in \mathbb{C} / L$, but what do I defined $F(z)$ to be for when $z \in L$?

Then I run the integration on $F$ instead of $f$ which is the same exact work shown, then I conclude by saying that

$0=\sum_{z \in \mathbb{C}}$ord$_z(F)$ = $\sum_{p \in X}$ord$_p(f)$

Any help or hint on my correspondence between $F$ and $f$? Since if $z \in L$, we are $0$ mod $L$, do you send $F(z)$ to $0$? I wanna say if $z \in L$ we just map $F(z)$ to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear. With $h$ meromorphic $1,t$ periodic with no zeros/poles on $a+n+mt+\Bbb{R},a+n+mt+\Bbb{R}t$ then $$\int_{[a,a+1]\cup[a+1,a+1+t]\cup[a+1+t,a+t]\cup[a+t,a]}h(z)dz$$ $$=\int_{[a,a+1]}-\int_{[a,a+1]}+\int_{[a,a+t]}-\int_{[a,a+t]}h(z)dz=0$$
When doing so with $h(z)=f'(z)/f(z)$  we get that $f$  meromorphic $1,t$ periodic 
 has the same number of zeros/poles on the fundamental paralellogram.

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question, all I am asking is an explicit way to show the 1-1 correspondence between meromorphic functions defined on the complex torus and meromorphic doubly periodic functions defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$ I already showed the integration, I am in an intro to Riemann Surfaces and we have not yet learned integration on Riemann surfaces, so I need to "reduce my problem" if you will down to regular old $\mathbb{C}$ just as you can do so when proving open mapping or maximum modulus for Riemann Surfaces, you invoke the respective theorems for general $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: maybe the answer to my question is just too trivial.

Comment: That's the definition : meromorphic on the complex torus $\Bbb{C/(Z+tZ)} $ = meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ and $1,t$ periodic. The "integration on the Riemann surface" reduces to integration on some curves in some charts. For the complex torus we have one surjective locally biholomorphic chart : the natural one, sending $z$ to $z+\Bbb{Z+tZ}$

Comment: Ok sweet thanks that makes complete sense! This is the explanation I was looking for precisely!